# Pass array to ajax request in $.ajax()

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have tried like this but could not get array list. It returns 'null'

```
 var data=[];
 data[0] = '1';
 data[1] = '2';
    $.ajax({                    
         url: '@Url.Action("AddFrequencyWeekly", "Plannar")',
         type: "POST",                     
         data: { data: data },
         dataType: 'json', 
         success: function (data) {                                            
             alert("Record Updated Successfully");    
                 }
         });
```

my model class code following

```
 public JsonResult AddFrequencyWeekly(string[] data)
        {

}
```

**data value says 'null'**

please help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
var datas = { data0: '1',
      data1: '2' };
$.ajax({                    
         url: '@Url.Action("AddFrequencyWeekly", "Plannar")',
         type: "POST",                     
         data: datas,
         dataType: 'json', 
         success: function (data) {                                            
             alert("Record Updated Successfully");    
                 }
         });
```

Comment: i cant get it. this could not redirect to that url page

Comment: @Sajith no this will asynchronously send the array `datas` to server. for example if you are using `django` you can get this array `datas` as `request.POST['data0']`

Comment: Hello suhail your code note working well how to solve this issue. could you please post that updated code

Comment: @Sajith could you please let me know what proggramming language you are using. i don't familiar with `'@Url.Action("AddFrequencyWeekly", "Plannar")',` . may be that might be wrong. i am good at `django`

Comment: using asp.net mvc4 and jquery

Comment: @Sajith sorry i am only familiar with `django`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36006/discussion-between-sajith-and-suhail)

Comment: @Sajith hey my home town is kerala, palakkad. nice to see a keraleite in stackoverflow.

Comment: hey iam also palakkad

Comment: your accurate place ?

Comment: @Sajith vadakkencherry

Comment: my place mannarkkad working @Cochin thanks for nice meet with you

Answer (score 0):

Its the way you are expecting to recive the data in the action method, 
try

```
public JsonResult AddFrequencyWeekly(IEnumeable<string> data)
{

}
```